# Проблемы с сетью FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

Поставил FreeBSD 9. Всё работало нормально, но на следующий день не стал видеть сеть, ни пингуется ни на прокси не хочет цепляться, то есть вообще ничего. ping выдает:

**ping: sendto: Host is down**

Что делать ума не приложу ?

Comment: Что куда пингуете, источник, назначение, схема сети, маршруты. Ну давайте же правильно формулировать вопросы.

Comment: компьютер подключен в свитч с остальными компами. Пингую именно их. Никакие маршруты и фаерволы ничего не ставил, можно сказать только что установленная голая ОСь

Comment: А сам себя пингует? Свой ипи? ипи по дхцп или статика?

Comment: адресс статический писал - ifconfig rl0 10.11.10.60 netmask 255.255.0.0сам себя пингует

Comment: А какой хост пингуете, и покажите таблицу маршрутизации.

Comment: А хост, который пингуете точно up?

Comment: Скопируйте вывод команд ifconfig, grep ifconfig /etc/rc.conf, ping того хоста, который вы пингуете, arp -an.